# Label placement over other features and labels in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, labeling, arcgis-pro, cartographic-information-model

I need place labels regardless of collisions with other layers. I use ArcPy and CIM. I need to place the label in the center of the polygon. At the same time, I need it not to change its position or disappear if it collides with another labels or feature. I try this code, but some labels are placed outside the polygons.

```
show_labels = m.listLayers("polygon23*")[0]
show_labels.showLabels = True

for lyr in m.listLayers("polygon23*"):
        if lyr.supports("SHOWLABELS"):
            if lyr.showLabels:
                for lblClass in lyr.listLabelClasses():
                    lblClass.expression = ''' "<FNT size='6'>" + $feature.label + "</FNT>"'''
                    
                    
label_show = m.listLayers('polygon23*')[0]
l_cim = label_show.getDefinition('V2')
lc = l_cim.labelClasses[0]

lc.maplexLabelPlacementProperties.polygonPlacementMethod = 'StraightInPolygon'
lc.maplexLabelPlacementProperties.placeOnlyInsidePolygon = True
lc.CIMStandardLabelPlacementProperties = 'allowOverlappingLabels'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been awhile since you asked but I wonder if adding the below code above your first maplex line would help?

`lc.maplexLabelPlacementProperties.MaplexPolygonFeatureType = "General"`

I'd bet you have this already, but in case you don't, [here's a link to a Maplex  engine github list](https://github.com/Esri/cim-spec/blob/master/docs/v2/CIMLabelPlacement.md#cimmaplexinternalzonepriorities). I kind of love it.